# Recently a paper published showed light could be slowed down 10,000 times. Could this be used to accelerate spacecraft as energy cannot be lost?

Tags: photons, speed-of-light, space, space-travel

Light has no mass. So simply assuming F = M x A Will generate a zero answer. However, in slowing down light there is a reduction in energy. Energy cannot be lost only transformed. People have theorised about solar photon sails in outer space. If they were giant and made of this new concept, would there be any resultant acceleration at all. No matter how small, it would be continous. With no friction in space could the craft eventually approach the speed of light?

Comment: *in slowing down light there is a reduction in energy* You sure? By $E = hf$, only the frequency matters.

Comment: @Allure:  $hf$ is the energy of a photon.  Slower light means fewer photons arriving per second, so less energy arriving per second, no?  [This, of  course, is taking the ""slower light" premise of the question as given.]

Comment: @WillO *Slower light means fewer photons arriving per second* - Does it? I'd have thought the number of photons arriving per second depends on the intensity. If you have slower light, then it takes longer for the photons to get to your detector once you turn the light on, but it doesn't change the intensity.

Comment: @Allure:  Fair enough.  I suppose it all depends on exactly what "slower light" means, which, given that there is no such thing, could be imagined to be pretty much anything at all.

Comment: @WillO not sure if it's what the OP is referring to, but strictly speaking there is such a thing as "slower light" - light in water for example is "slower" than light in a vacuum.

Comment: The article was https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/scientists-slowed-down-light-by-10000-times-in-an-experiment/ar-BB1i5HfY  which included the sentence but the approach also means a lot of the light and energy is lost along the way.